# How do I set dynamic values in animation between activities?

Tags: android, animation

I need to animate incoming activity using a custom animation, where some values are calculated at runtime.

Currently I know this:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.leave);
```

But this only works with XML animations.

Is there a way/trick/hack to set a programmatic animation or change the parameters?

A possibility could be to animate the "leave" part before starting the new activity, and "enter" part in onFocusChanged / onResume of the new activity, but this will not work (already tested a bit), because the old activity has to be visible while the new activity is appearing.

Another thing which comes to my mind is to generate the XML anim file at runtime, save in the folder and use it in `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.leave);`. I would do this at the app start or similar, when some parameters, like exact screen size are known. But I don't know if it's possible.

Developing for API 7, support package...

Thanks in advance.